# Cryt Error with clicking button

Tags: android

recently I've made an app with buttons and by click each button you should go to another activity with the text. And it works great. But when I decited to add another one and programming it, I have cryt error when I click this button and I dont know what's going on. Here I give you the code (if necessery I will give you link to whole project but it have 135 MB weight).

MainActivity.java:

```
package pl.wrweb.reikoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button buttonOk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}


}
```

ButtonsActivity.java:

```
package pl.wrweb.reikoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class ButtonsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String CLOSE = "close";
public static final String OPTION = "option";

private Button firstButton, secondButton, oBlondynkach, thirdButton, forthButton, fifthButton, sixthButton, seventhButton, closeButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttons);

    firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
    secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondButton);
    oBlondynkach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blondynki);
    thirdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdButton);
    forthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forthButton);
    fifthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fifthButton);
    sixthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sixthButton);
    seventhButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seventhButton);
    closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeButton);

    firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    oBlondynkach.setOnClickListener(this);
    thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    forthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    fifthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    seventhButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(md5(androidId).toUpperCase())
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String idAsString = v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
    String option = idAsString.replace("pl.wrweb.reikoapp:id/", "").replace("Button", "");
    if (option.equals(CLOSE)) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ButtonsActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(OPTION, option);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public String md5(String s) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

TextActivity.java:

```
package pl.wrweb.reikoapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TextActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String OPTION = "option";
private TextView optionTV, textTV;
private Button backButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);

    optionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optionTV);
    textTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTV);
    backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);

    String option = getIntent().getStringExtra(OPTION);
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int optionId = getResources().getIdentifier(option + ".option", "string", packageName);
    int textId = getResources().getIdentifier(option + ".text", "string", packageName);

    optionTV.setText(optionId);
    textTV.setText(textId);


    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextActivity.this.onBackPressed();
        }
    });



}


}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloTV"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/laugh"
        android:layout_below="@+id/helloTV"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/ok.click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_buttons.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choose"
            android:id="@+id/chooseTV"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first.option"
            android:id="@+id/firstButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chooseTV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second.option"
            android:id="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third.option"
            android:id="@+id/thirdButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forth.option"
            android:id="@+id/forthButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirdButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirdButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fifth.option"
            android:id="@+id/fifthButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/forthButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sixth.option"
            android:id="@+id/sixthButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fifthButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fifthButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fifthButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/seventh.option"
            android:id="@+id/seventhButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sixthButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sixthButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sixthButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/close.option"
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seventhButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seventhButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seventhButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button.width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/oBlondynkach.option"
            android:id="@+id/blondynki"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/secondButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/blondynki"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/secondButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

activity_text.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/optionTV"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/optionTV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:singleLine="false"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Logcat:

> 01-18 12:42:33.359 3188-3188/pl.wrweb.reikoapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.wrweb.reikoapp/pl.wrweb.reikoapp.TextActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:243)
>                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
>                                                                        at **pl.wrweb.reikoapp.TextActivity.onCreate(TextActivity.java:30)**
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
>                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: whats your error in logcat?

Comment: Ive pasted logcat quote in my topic.

Comment: Your logcat says that check Line 30 in your TextActivity class

Comment: I have no idea why - it worked before adding this button. Others buttons works fine except this one which I added.

Comment: Show your xml. Looks like you are referencing an id which does not exist in your xml.

Comment: @barq - done - pasted in topic.